# css, fixed item not causing body to scroll (getting cut off)

Tags: html, css

I have a position fixed menu that is right inside my body, and is toggled hidden and shown via a button on the page the user can click. The problem I am having is this menu can get decently big (it pulls dynamic content via server) and sometimes it will be longer than the body, however when it spills over the bottom of the page, the page does not expand to scroll for it (it gets cut off).

I tried

```
body{
overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

which did not seem to effect it. Here is the css(sass) of the item itself.

```
.globalMenu
position: fixed
top: 75px
left: 50%
width: 350px
margin-left: -175px
height: auto
padding: 5px
z-index: 1001
background-color: #28282e
box-shadow: 0 14px 28px rgba(0,0,0,0.25), 0 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.22)
@media screen and (max-width: 600px)
    width: 100%
    margin-left: 0
    left: 0
```

So I'm not sure what I'm missing here - something about how fixed works maybe? Thanks for reading!

Comment: Please include your HTML as well. However, you should apply `overflow` properties to the elements you want to scroll/be hidden, not to the body.

Comment: @TylerH here is the raw html - http://plnkr.co/edit/voFN5YLCqP47WhUDq8RY?p=preview - it is just right under the body tag. I would like the body to expand when this item grows outside of the body (if possible)

Comment: Fixed position elements are just outside the flow of the document ,,, that means the size of those elements doesn't take space on the layout and then can't increase the size of the container

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed items are **taken out of the document flow**, so even if its dimensions exceed those of the viewport, the containing element (be it `<body>` or any other descendants) will not accommodate it with scrollbars.

To put it in another way, **the `<body>` element would have no access to the dimensions of the `position: fixed` element**, and therefore assigning overflow property on the body will not have any effect of allowing users to access hidden content of said element.

Instead, assign the `overflow-y: auto` property to the fixed element instead:

```
.globalMenu
overflow-y: auto;
position: fixed
top: 75px
left: 50%
width: 350px
margin-left: -175px
height: auto
padding: 5px
z-index: 1001
background-color: #28282e
box-shadow: 0 14px 28px rgba(0,0,0,0.25), 0 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.22)
@media screen and (max-width: 600px)
    width: 100%
    margin-left: 0
    left: 0
```

See proof-of-concept fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/38bsqLsb/1/

Comment: I am trying to avoid adding overflow to the item itself, but this is a correct answer and I will mark it as such. Thank you!